# Show minimum distance to a convex set is a convex function.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Show that

$$
g(x)=\inf_{z \in C}\|x-z\|
$$
where $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $C$ is a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (nor close neither bounded), and $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $x,y$ be in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We need to show that

$$
g(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda)g(y) \tag{1}
$$

I tried the following:

$$
\|\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y-z\| \leq \lambda\| x -z\| + (1-\lambda)\| y-z\| \,\, \forall {z \in C}
$$
Since

$$
g(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y)=\inf_{z \in C}\|\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y-z\| \leq \|\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y-z\| \,\, \forall {z \in C}
$$

So

$$
g(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y)=\inf_{z \in C}\|\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y-z\| \leq \lambda\| x -z\| + (1-\lambda)\| y-z\| \,\, \forall {z \in C}
$$

I do not know how to handle the right hand side and apply infimum in a right way because the following is not correct in general

$$
\inf_{z \in C}\|\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y-z\| \nleq \lambda \inf_{z \in C} \| x -z\| + (1-\lambda) \inf_{z \in C} \| y-z\| 
$$

Or maybe my initial way to prove the convexity is wrong. Can you complete my proof or show the claim using another way?

Comment: Hint: you can prove this for any jointly convex function $f(x,z)$, not just for $f(x,z) = ||x-z||$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $C$ is also closed, there exists $z_1,z_2\in C$ such that $g(x)=||x-z_1||$, $g(y)=||y-z_2||$. Then $$\lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda)g(y)\ge ||\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y - \lambda z_1-(1-\lambda)z_2||.$$ Using the convexity of $C$, $z=\lambda z_1+ (1-\lambda)z_2\in C$. Hence, $$\lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda)g(y)\ge ||\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y - z||\ge g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y).$$ If $C$ is not closed, probably some limit argument may plus the above reasoning should work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda \in (0,1)$. Note that by definition of $g$, we have

$\forall \frac{1}{2n}>0, x_n \in  C$  such that $||x-x_n||<g(x)+\frac{1}{2n}$

$\forall \frac{1}{2n}>0, y_n \in  C$  such that $||y-y_n||<g(y)+\frac{1}{2n}$

Set $z=\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$ and $z_n = \lambda x_n + (1-\lambda)y_n \in C$ (from convexity). Now, we obtain

$||z-z_n|| = ||\lambda (x-x_n) + (1-\lambda)(y-y_n)|| \leq \lambda ||x-x_n||+(1-\lambda)||y-y_n||< \lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda) g(y)+\frac{1}{n}$

$\implies inf_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \; ||z-z_n|| \leq   inf_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \;  [\lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda)g(y)+\frac{1}{n}] = \lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda) g(y)$

Note note that $(z_n)$ is a sequence in C (which follows from convexity). Hence,

$ g(z)= inf_{c \in C } \; ||z-c||  \leq  inf_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \; ||z-z_n|| \leq \lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda) g(y) $

$\implies g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda g(x)+ (1-\lambda) g(y)$

Hence, $g$ is convex.

Q.E.D.

I am not sure. It might be wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Hint: try starting from the opposite direction, consider the subadditivity of the infimum and see if you can show it that way

Comment: Your statement is not an answer, please write it as a comment and delete your answer.